# How to find a value in a pandas column and make it its own column but the column isn't organized

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, split

So I'm working on comparing data from one dataframe to another. My CSVs are formatted like this.
DF1:

| Name | Connections |
| --- | --- |
| SIGNAL 1 | DF62.1 P8.S12 P105.H10 RK121.2 |
| SIGNAL 2 | DF57.1 P105.B4 P7.S5 |

DF2:

| Name | Connections |
| --- | --- |
| SIGNAL 1 | D101.1 K154A.4 P8.S12 |
| SIGNAL 2 | K140A.3 P7.S5 |

I want to extract the P8.S12 and P7.S5 to its own column. Any ideas how to pull out that specific value? It will always be a P#.S# value where the P# is between P1-P12, and S# is between S1-S112. ex. P1.S5, P4.S100, P3.S30...

My other issue is in DF1 SIGNAL 1, P105 isn't what I want P1-12 are the values anything bigger than 12 should not be extracted.

I've looked into the split function with a space delimiter but since the value isn't always in the same order in the column I don't think this would work.

Comment: "*Any ideas how to pull out that specific value*" -> what is the logic? How does it generalize?

Comment: It will always be a P#.S# value where the P# is between P1-P12, and S# is between S1-S112

Comment: @cavediver what should happen if you have several matches in a row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a regex and [`str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) to match `PX.SY` where X is a number between 1-12 and Y is 1-112:

```
pattern = r'(P(?:[1-9]|1[012])\.S(?:[1-9]|\d{2}|10\d|11[012])\b)'
df['new'] = df['Connections'].str.extract(pattern)
```

If you can have multiple matches and want all of them, go with [`str.extractall`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extractall.html) + [`groupby.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html):

```
df['new'] = (df['Connections'].str.extractall(pattern)
             .groupby(level=0).agg(' '.join)
            )
```

Output:

```
       Name                     Connections     new
0  SIGNAL 1  DF62.1 P8.S12 P105.H10 RK121.2  P8.S12
1  SIGNAL 2            DF57.1 P105.B4 P7.S5   P7.S5
```

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/6V4d2k/1)

*NB. generating a regex for a range in not always straightforward, you have to break the pattern in chunks (e.g. 0-9 OR 10-19 OR 100-109 OR 110-112 in the case of 1-112). If needed, there are online tools to help you with that ([here](https://3widgets.com/?min=1&max=112&output=) is a random one).*

Answer (score 0):

Let's start by decomposing your problem in two parts.

- Create a regex function that matches your desired values from a larger string
- Apply that formula to the dataframe to create a new filtered column

In it's simple case, we are going to match here just the P#.S# values. As suggested we are going to use pandas and the regex modules:

```
import pandas as pd
import re
```

Also we recreate your original dataframe df1:

```
# Define the data
dict_df1 = {
    'Name':['SIGNAL 1','SIGNAL 2'],
    'Connections':['DF62.1 P8.S12 P105.H10 RK121.2','DF57.1 P105.B4 P7.S5'],
}
dict_df2={'Name':['SIGNAL 1','SIGNAL 2'], 'Connections':['D101.1 K154A.4 P8.S12','K140A.3 P7.S5']}
# Create the dataframes
df1 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict_df1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict_df2)
```

We check the information is OK

```
df1
       Name                     Connections
0  SIGNAL 1  DF62.1 P8.S12 P105.H10 RK121.2
1  SIGNAL 2            DF57.1 P105.B4 P7.S5

df2
       Name            Connections
0  SIGNAL 1  D101.1 K154A.4 P8.S12
1  SIGNAL 2          K140A.3 P7.S5
```

Now the interesting part, we create a extract value function returning all the matches (in your case only one):

```
def extract_value(string):
   x = re.findall("P\d+\.S\d+", string)
   return " ".join(x)
```

and with all the ingredients, you create a new column in your dataframes applying the function

```
df1['Extracted connections'] = df1['Connections'].apply(extract_value)
df2['Extracted connections'] = df2['Connections'].apply(extract_value)

df1
       Name                     Connections Extracted connections
0  SIGNAL 1  DF62.1 P8.S12 P105.H10 RK121.2                P8.S12
1  SIGNAL 2            DF57.1 P105.B4 P7.S5                 P7.S5

df2
       Name            Connections Extracted connections
0  SIGNAL 1  D101.1 K154A.4 P8.S12                P8.S12
1  SIGNAL 2          K140A.3 P7.S5                 P7.S5
```

Now, you can extend your regex magic in the extract_value function to delimiter the range of the P and S values according to regex:
https://www.regextutorial.org/regex-for-numbers-and-ranges.php

Comment: Why use `apply()` instead of the built-in `.str.extract()`?

Comment: `P\d+\.S\d+` is too broad and would incorrectly match `P13-S200` for instance

Comment: Using ```apply()``` is just a more abstract way, probably slower but which allows the extraction to be customized with a function. For the specific solution yes, ```str.extract()``` is better suited.

Comment: You are right @mozway. The ```P\d+\.S\d+``` is just the starting point to understand the regex method, since the actual regex for your question ```(P(?:[1-9]|1[012])\.S(?:[1-9]|\d{2}|10\d|11[012])\b)``` is unfortunately not very appealing to start learning.